# How to format a fiscal quarter?

Tags: date

I'm trying to input financial statements into excel and want to do it quarterly. What would be the best formula that I can continue to drag right that would give me something like:

```
Q1'18 |  Q2'18 | Q3'18 | Q4'18 | Q1'19
```

Ideally the code can be used to start on any quarter like Q1'10 for example

Answer (score 1):

in A1 put 1/1/2019. In B1 :

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+3,DAY(A1))
```

and drag right-wards. in A2 :

```
="Q"&CHOOSE(MONTH(A1),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)&"'"&RIGHT(YEAR(A1),2)
```

and drag right-wards.

Hope you get what you need.. ( :

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula to increment quarter in each cell, just fill initial value in first cell then insert formula for all cells in the right.

`="Q"&(MOD(MID(A1,2,1),4)+1)&"'"&RIGHT(A1,2)+IF(MID(A1,2,1)="4",1,0)`

[image]